# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] is always null

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the value for the key "sUser" in appSetting section from app.config

this is the code on my class.cs

```
string sUsr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get["sUser"];
```

But always its null.

I try this code (I took it from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingssection.settings.aspx)):

```
// Get the configuration file.
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

// Get the appSettings section.
AppSettingsSection appSettings = (AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection("appSettings");

// Get the auxiliary file name.
Console.WriteLine("Auxiliary file: {0}", config.AppSettings.File);
```

But it shows that the file Empty

Also I am using the stting console to write those properties and it works if I get the apps using

```
string sUsr = WIW.Business.Properties.Settings.Default.sUser;
```

But I am going to use that class as a reference in a website and on the web.config of the site I can't configure those settings

Comment: Can you paste the AppSettings section of your web.config as a reference?  On a side note, you shouldn't even need to use `config.GetSection("appSettings")`.

Answer (score 3):

In your App.config the appSettings section should look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="sUser" value="Test"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Properties.Settings.Default.{your_setting_key}` to access the value

I.E

```
Properties.Settings.Default.sPassword return 8909039388
```

All these were included in Properties Class.

Answer (score 0):

Here its my app.config, if I try to get the key values from the appSettings sections I always get null, but If I try to get them from applicationsection Its no problem, the thing is that I need put that applicationsection on a web site but on a web site i can put applicationSettings

```
<configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="sUser" value="userbancolombia"> 
        <add key="sPassword" value="8909039388"> 
      <appSettings>

      <configSections>
            <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
                <section name="WIW.Business.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
            </sectionGroup>
        </configSections>
        
      <system.serviceModel>
            <bindings />
            <client />
        </system.serviceModel>
      
      
      
      <applicationSettings>
        <WIW.Business.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="WIW_Business_WsCCMain_ConsultaNuips" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://coomeva1/AsisaWS_2008/ConsultaNuips.asmx</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="WIW_Business_WsCCAux_ConsultaNuips" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://coomeva1/AsisaWS_2008_Sec/ConsultaNuips.asmx</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="WIW_Business_WsCEMain_ConsultaCedulaExtranjeria"
            serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://coomeva1/AsisaWS_2008/ConsultaCedulaExtranjeria.asmx</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="WIW_Business_WsCEAux_ConsultaCedulaExtranjeria"
            serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://coomeva1/AsisaWS_2008_Sec/ConsultaCedulaExtranjeria.asmx</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="sUser" serializeAs="String">
            <value>userbancolombia</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="sPassword" serializeAs="String">
            <value>8909039388</value>
          </setting>
        </WIW.Business.Properties.Settings>
      </applicationSettings>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was calling another project(In the same solution) and was expecting the appSettings to be present.

To make it work,I added the following lines in the application that was calling the target application.

```
  <appSettings>
        <add key="sUser" value="Test"/>
  </appSettings>
```

It worked for me after that. Try this. It might help you too